# A business email puzzle: Can you combine gmail for staff emails, with another server for a larger-volume sendgrid emails?

Tags: email, email-server, gmail, mailing-list, sendgrid

We use Google for Business for our staff emails. But we also want to send out automated emails as part of a web-app. Gmail limits the number of emails you can send with a cap (a few hundred a day?), and the automated emails will exceed that.

Is it possible to have e.g. alice@mydomain.com handled by gmail, whilst automated@mydomain.com uses a different email server?

Or is the solution to use two different domains?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can send outgoing emails from any server you want. You should add that server's IP address to your SPF record, though. Most email services like sendgrid will have [instructions on how to do this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/glossary/spf/).